# It is not possible to correctly write functions from MSDN in Delphi

Tags: pointers, delphi, delphi-7, directshow

I want to create my own filter and use it in the [DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow) library. The filter seemed to be able to write, but there was a problem with creating a graph. I based my code on the ["Creating an Audio Capture Graph"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/creating-an-audio-capture-graph) article. At the very end it says that the functions from the articles ["Add a Filter by CLSID"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/add-a-filter-by-clsid) and ["Connect Two Filters"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/connect-two-filters) are also used. I rewrote the most identical, but the code does not work.

I indicated the location of the error with many "!".

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class AEccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0045AAA8 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000000'. Process stopped. Use step or Run to continue.

In general, I have the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, DirectShow9,ActiveX,BaseClass, DirectInput,
  StdCtrls,DirectSound, DirectSetup,  DirectPlay8,   DirectMusic,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function AddFilterByCLSID(pGraphA: IGraphBuilder; clsid: TGUID; wazName: PWideChar;  ppF: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
    function ConnectFilter( pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pSrc: IBaseFilter; pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
    function GetUnconnectedPin(pFilter: IBaseFilter; PinDir: PIN_DIRECTION; ppPin: IPin): HRESULT;
    function ConnectFilterPin( pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pOut: IPin; pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  end;
var
  PropertyName:IPropertyBag;
  pSrc, pWaveDest, pWriter: IBaseFilter; 
  pSink: IFileSinkFilter;
  pGraph: IGraphBuilder;
  FMediaControl: IMediaControl;
  pDevEnum: ICreateDevEnum;
  pEnum: IEnumMoniker;
  pMoniker: IMoniker;
  MArray1,MArray2: array of IMoniker;

  hr: HRESULT;

  DeviceName:OleVariant;
  FAudioCaptureFilter:  IBaseFilter;
const
  CLSID_WavDest : TGUID = '{3C78B8E2-6C4D-11d1-ADE2-0000F8754B99}';
  CLSID_CRleFilter: TGUID = '{BEBCF0A3-2673-42A7-82F2-5D4FC3126171}'; //My Filter.
  IID_ICRleFilter: TGUID = '{35C0AC80-C3E4-4EEA-A1F5-049401E29400}'; //Myfilter
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.AddFilterByCLSID(pGraphA: IGraphBuilder; clsid: TCLSID;
  wazName: PWideChar; ppF: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
var
 pF: IBaseFilter;
begin
 CoCreateInstance(clsid, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, pF);
 hr:=pGraph.AddFilter(pF, WazName);

   if hr<> S_OK then
   begin
   ShowMessage('фильтр вавдеста не добавился');
   end;
   PPf:= pF;
//   pF._Release;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   pOut: IPin;
begin
 HR:= CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                   IID_IGraphBuilder, pGraph);

 if hr<> S_OK then
   begin
   ShowMessage('Граф не создался');
   end;
  HR:= CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
IID_ICreateDevEnum, pDevEnum);
 if hr<> S_OK then
   begin
   ShowMessage('перечеслитель не создался');
   Exit;
   end;


    HR:=pDevEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory, pEnum, 0);
if HR<>S_OK  then EXIT;
//Обнуляем массив в списке моникеров
setlength(MArray2,0);
//Пускаем массив по списку устройств
while (S_OK=pEnum.Next(1,pMoniker,Nil)) do
begin
setlength(MArray2,length(MArray2)+1); //Увеличиваем массив на единицу
MArray2[length(MArray2)-1]:=pMoniker; //Запоминаем моникер в масиве
HR:=pMoniker.BindToStorage(NIL, NIL, IPropertyBag, PropertyName); //Линкуем моникер устройства к формату хранения IPropertyBag
if FAILED(HR) then Continue;
HR:=PropertyName.Read('FriendlyName', DeviceName, NIL); //Получаем имя устройства
if FAILED(HR) then Continue;
//Добавляем имя устройства в списки
Listbox2.Items.Add(DeviceName);
end;
 Listbox2.ItemIndex:=0;
   MArray2[Listbox2.ItemIndex].BindToObject(NIL, NIL, IID_IBaseFilter, FAudioCaptureFilter);
              //добавляем устройство в граф фильтров
              Pgraph.AddFilter(FAudioCaptureFilter, 'AudioCaptureFilter');
 // pGraph.AddFilter(pSrc, 'Capture');

  AddfilterByCLSID(pGraph, CLSID_CRleFilter, '_CRleFilter', pWaveDest);



  ConnectFilter(pGraph, pWaveDest, pWriter); // This is where the mistakes start !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  pGraph.QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, FMediaControl);

 FMediaControl.Run();
end;
{
There is no function overloading in Delphi, so I named the functions differently
                                                                                }
function TForm1.ConnectFilterPin(pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pOut: IPin;
  pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  var
 pIn : IPin;
begin
  pIn:= nil;
  GetUnconnectedPin(pdest, PINDIR_OUTPUT, pIn);
  pGraph.Connect(pOut, pin);
end;

function TForm1.ConnectFilter(pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pSrc: IBaseFilter;
  pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  var
    pOut: IPin;
begin
  //pOut:= 0;


   GetUnconnectedPin(pSrc, PINDIR_OUTPUT, pOut);
   ConnectFilterPin(pGraph, pOut, pdest);

end;

function TForm1.GetUnconnectedPin(pFilter: IBaseFilter;
  PinDir: PIN_DIRECTION; ppPin:  IPin): HRESULT;
var
 pEnum: IEnumPins;
 pPin: IPin;
 hr: HRESULT;
 ThisPinDir : PIN_DIRECTION;
 pTmp: IPin;
begin
  pTmp:=nil;
  ppPin:= nil;
 // pEnum:= nil;
  pPin:= nil;
 hr:= pFilter.EnumPins(pEnum); // This is where the error occurs !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  if hr<> S_OK then
  begin
    ShowMessage('перечесление пинов: не равно S_OK');
  end;

  while pEnum.Next(1, pPin, nil) = S_OK do
  begin
   pPin.QueryDirection(ThisPinDir);
   if ThisPinDir = PinDir then
    begin
     hr:= pPin.ConnectedTo(pTmp);
          if Succeeded(hr) then
           begin
            pTmp._Release;
           end else
           begin
           pEnum._Release;
           ppPin:= pPin;
           Result := S_OK;
           Exit;
           end;


          end;
       end;
      pPin._Release;
       
  ShowMessage('ошибка: не правильный код');
  Result:= E_FAIL;
 // ShowMessage('ошибка: не правильный код');

end;

end.
```

I was hoping that the error was caused by pointers, or rather their absence. I tried to put them in absolutely all combinations, but this did not lead to the desired result. Besides, everywhere in Delphi pointers are not used at all. Perhaps somewhere the parameters in the functions are not correctly passed. I reviewed all the functions 5 times, tried to find errors, but this did not work. Using pointers didn't work either.

I know the error is small and easy to fix, but I can't figure out where it is.

Comment: An Access Violation at address 0 means a `nil` pointer is being dereferenced. The debugger should take you to the exact code that crashed. Use the debugger to find the `nil` pointer so you can fix the code that uses it. For instance, I see a number of places in your code where you are not checking API calls for failures, or at least are not stopping your code from using pointers returned from failed API calls.

Comment: There are plenty of things in your code that are not right. First you should not call `_Release` as interface references are automatically managed - this is critical error. Next, in your `AddFilterByCLSID` method, you are assigning `pF` to the `ppF` parameter, but that assignment does not make sense, unless you want to return that instance and in that case you need to mark that parameter with `var ppF: IBaseFilter`. Also you don't have to initialize interface references to nil as they will be automatically initialized. This might not be all...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no book "how to translate from C++ to Delphi". Because of this, I am having difficulty. I didn't originally use `pF` because I don't see the point in it, but MSDN knows better than me, so I added. `_release` is also used by MSDN, although I know for sure that Delphi always handles memory release. I used `out` instead of `var`. There was a question about symbols `**` is `var` in Delphi?

Comment: I don't understand the differences. Why MSDN uses pointers, while Delphi doesn't. Also called `Release` in MSDN, not used again in Delphi. It's poorly described on the internet.
I racked my brains trying to understand and use these moments correctly, but the error turned out to be much simpler. It took me a week (1-3 hours a day) to understand that it's not about pointers. I found my mistakes. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not in the pointers. The purpose of the `Connect Filter` function is to connect two filters. The structure looks like this `ConnectFilter(Graph, Filter 1, Filter 2);`. I added only one filter to the project. As a result, nothing was sent to the function instead of the second filter. There was an address reading error that was very hard to catch. Perhaps it would be easy to identify the error if I used all sorts of checks. Due to the fact that C ++ uses pointers, but Delphi does not, I thought that the error was in pointers, because I did not use them. But the fix turned out to be simpler: you need to add a second filter, and send it as the third parameter.
From these errors we can conclude:

1. Even in experimental code, it is worth doing as many checks as possible.
2. Watch and read carefully.
3. Functions that are called from other functions should be above these functions. There was no error, but it is indicated in the book Flenov M.E. The Bible of Delphi (third edition), chapter 5.4: Procedures and functions in Delphi. Solutions to other errors are also described there.
4. Unlike C++, Delphi does not need to assign `nil` to new variables, Delphi does it on its own.
5. You also don't need to call `Release` yourself.

I rewrote the code with the correction of all the errors I noticed. I'll leave it below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, DirectShow9,ActiveX,BaseClass, DirectInput,
  StdCtrls,DirectSound, DirectSetup,  DirectPlay8,   DirectMusic,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function AddFilterByCLSID(pGraphA: IGraphBuilder; clsid: TGUID; wazName: PWideChar; var ppF: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
    function ConnectFilter( pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pSrc: IBaseFilter; pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
    function GetUnconnectedPin(pFilter: IBaseFilter; PinDir: PIN_DIRECTION; var ppPin: IPin): HRESULT;
    function ConnectFilterPin( pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pOut: IPin; pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  end;
var
  PropertyName:IPropertyBag;
  pSrc, pWaveDest, pWriter: IBaseFilter;
  pSink: IFileSinkFilter;
  pGraph: IGraphBuilder;
  FMediaControl: IMediaControl;
  pDevEnum: ICreateDevEnum;
  pEnum: IEnumMoniker;
  pMoniker: IMoniker;
  MArray1,MArray2: array of IMoniker;

  hr: HRESULT;

  DeviceName:OleVariant;
  FAudioCaptureFilter:  IBaseFilter;
const
  CLSID_WavDest : TGUID = '{3C78B8E2-6C4D-11d1-ADE2-0000F8754B99}';
  CLSID_CRleFilter: TGUID = '{BEBCF0A3-2673-42A7-82F2-5D4FC3126171}';
  IID_ICRleFilter: TGUID = '{35C0AC80-C3E4-4EEA-A1F5-049401E29400}';
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.AddFilterByCLSID(pGraphA: IGraphBuilder; clsid: TCLSID;
  wazName: PWideChar; var ppF: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  {The last parameter of the function is returned,
   for this you need to add [ var ] before the declaration.
   Возвращается последний параметр функции,
    для этого вам нужно добавить [ var ] перед объявлением.}
var
  pf: IBaseFilter;
begin
  hr:= CoCreateInstance(clsid, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, pF);
    if Succeeded(hr) then               // Added full error checking
    begin
      hr:=pGraph.AddFilter(pF, WazName);
      if Succeeded(hr) then
      begin
       ppf:= pf;
      end else
       ShowMessage('фильтр добавился / Filter not added');
    end else
     ShowMessage('фильтр добавился / Filter not added 2');
   Result:= hr;
end;

function TForm1.GetUnconnectedPin(pFilter: IBaseFilter;
  PinDir: PIN_DIRECTION; var ppPin:  IPin): HRESULT;
var
 pEnum: IEnumPins;
 pPin: IPin;
 hr: HRESULT;
 ThisPinDir : PIN_DIRECTION;
 pTmp: IPin;
begin
  //you don't need to assign [ nil ]; Delphi does it by itself.
  //Не нужно явно указывать [ nil ]; Delphi делает это самостоятельно.
 hr:= pFilter.EnumPins(pEnum);

  if Failed(hr) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('перечесление пинов: ошибка / pin listing: error');
  end;

  while pEnum.Next(1, pPin, nil) = S_OK do
  begin
   pPin.QueryDirection(ThisPinDir);
   if ThisPinDir = PinDir then
    begin
     hr:= pPin.ConnectedTo(pTmp);
          if Succeeded(hr) then
           begin
           end else
           begin
           ppPin:= pPin;
           Result := S_OK;
           Exit;
           end;
    end;
  end;

  ShowMessage('ошибка: не правильный код / error: invalid code');
  Result:= E_FAIL;

end;

function TForm1.ConnectFilterPin(pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pOut: IPin;
  pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  var
 pIn : IPin;
begin
 GetUnconnectedPin(pdest, PINDIR_OUTPUT, pIn);
 pGraph.Connect(pOut, pin);
end;

function TForm1.ConnectFilter(pGraph: IGraphBuilder; pSrc: IBaseFilter;
  pdest: IBaseFilter): HRESULT;
  var
    pOut: IPin;
begin
   GetUnconnectedPin(pSrc, PINDIR_OUTPUT, pOut);
   ConnectFilterPin(pGraph, pOut, pdest);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   pOut: IPin;
begin
 HR:= CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                   IID_IGraphBuilder, pGraph);

 if hr<> S_OK then
   begin
   ShowMessage('Ошибка создания графа / Graph creation error');
   end;
  HR:= CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
IID_ICreateDevEnum, pDevEnum);
 if hr<> S_OK then
   begin
   ShowMessage('Ошибка создания графа / Graph creation error');
   Exit;
   end;


    HR:=pDevEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory, pEnum, 0);
if HR<>S_OK  then EXIT;
 //Обнуляем массив в списке моникеров  /  Resetting the array in the list of monikers
 setlength(MArray2,0);
 //Пускаем массив по списку устройств  /  Let's run the array through the list of devices
while (S_OK=pEnum.Next(1,pMoniker,Nil)) do
begin
 setlength(MArray2,length(MArray2)+1); //Увеличиваем массив на единицу  /  Incrementing the array by one
 MArray2[length(MArray2)-1]:=pMoniker; //Запоминаем моникер в масиве  /  Remembering the moniker in the array
 HR:=pMoniker.BindToStorage(NIL, NIL, IPropertyBag, PropertyName); //Линкуем моникер устройства к формату хранения IPropertyBag
                                                                  // Link Device Monitor to IPropertyBag Storage Format
 if FAILED(HR) then Continue;
 HR:=PropertyName.Read('FriendlyName', DeviceName, NIL); //Получаем имя устройства  /  Getting the device name
 if FAILED(HR) then Continue;
 //Добавляем имя устройства в списки  /  Adding the device name to the lists
 Listbox2.Items.Add(DeviceName);
end;
 Listbox2.ItemIndex:=0;
 MArray2[Listbox2.ItemIndex].BindToObject(NIL, NIL, IID_IBaseFilter, FAudioCaptureFilter);
              //добавляем устройство в граф фильтров  /  adding a device to the filter graph

  Pgraph.AddFilter(FAudioCaptureFilter, 'AudioCaptureFilter');
  AddfilterByCLSID(pGraph, CLSID_FileWriter, 'File Writer', pWriter);
  AddfilterByCLSID(pGraph, CLSID_CRleFilter, '_CRleFilter', pWaveDest);

  {The error was that [ ConnectFilter ] connects two filters, and only one was specified.
   The first filter is specified in the second parameter; the second filter is
   specified in the third parameter; In order for the function to execute correctly,
   you must first add two filters, then use [ ConnectFilter ] }

  {Ошибка заключалась в том что [ ConnectFilter ] соединяет два фильтра,
   а задавался только один. Первый фильтр указан во втором параметре;
   второй фильтр указывается в третьем параметре; Что бы функция выполнилась правильно,
   нужно предварительно добавить два фильтра, затем использовать [ ConnectFilter ] }

  ConnectFilter(pGraph, FAudioCaptureFilter, pWaveDest);
  ConnectFilter(pGraph, pWaveDest, pWriter);

  pGraph.QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, FMediaControl);
  FMediaControl.Run();
end;

end.
```